# How can I slice array values?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I slice array values? For example, I have:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I need:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], ...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.each_cons(2).to_a
#=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]]
```